# c# Using TextFieldParser to read .csv but unable to replace the created lists empty entries with "0"

Tags: c#, textfieldparser

New to c#. I am reading two columns from a .csv file and creating a `IEnumerable<string[]>`. I have the code below that is working, but sometimes a row can be empty (shown by the half height row in the table below) and in that case I would like to replace it with the string "0". Any empty cell is shown as "" in the list when I debug the code.

| Lat | Lng |
| --- | --- |
| 51.452703 | 36.622065 |
|  |  |
| 28.721829 | 41.013330 |

Raw csv data format:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Lat,Lng,Col9
one street,300,,,GUANGDONG,CN,,,
```

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCSV(string path)
{
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

        parser.ReadFields(); // read past the header
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            yield return parser.ReadFields().Skip(6).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my attempt to replace the "" with "0", but I am getting the error: string cannot be of zero length, paramenter name oldValue. I understand from that, that it needs something to search for. But I'm not sure where to go now.

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCSV(string path)
{
    string[] test;

    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

        parser.ReadFields(); // read past the header
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            test = parser.ReadFields().Skip(6).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray();
            var replacedNames = test.Select(x => x.Replace("", "0")).ToArray();
            yield return replacedNames;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share your CSV data as raw text rather than as a formatted table?  In order to debug your problem we need to be able to paste the CSV + code into a console app or fiddle and run, but it isn't really clear how `parser.ReadFields().Skip(6).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray()` will interact with the table shown in your question.  Thanks!

Comment: [`string.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) *Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.*, so what would you expect that to do if the input string is an empty string?  Maybe you want something like `x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) ? "0" : x` ?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what to try. I ran that and realised it wouldn't work. But finding it hard to get the right search term in google to find something. Bit new to this sorry.

Comment: Are you using the obsolete Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser? This class was created only as a convenience to allow VB6 developers to migrate to .NET 20+ years ago. By today's standards it's slow, cumbersome and uses a ton of memory  Use a modern library instead, like CsvHelper or Sep

Comment: @dbc I have amended my question to add the raw csv data format. Thank you.

Comment: Great thanks.  Do you still need help or did `x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) ? "0" : x` resolve your problems?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - `TextFieldParser` isn't marked as obsolete.  If all you need to do is to read through a CSV file and pick out some specific columns by index, and you want to do it with minimal code + 3rd party packages, it's adequate.  Where `CsvHelper` shines is in round-tripping CSV data and handling arbitrary column order.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm not familiar with `Sep` though.  Is this it?  https://github.com/nietras/Sep

Comment: @dbc it's obsolete as in the English word obsolete. As this question proves, the code isn't minimal. It's a legacy third-party class from the VB runtime. It's not exactly actively maintained, [the last meaningful fix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commits/b6e20b854e0cae678b464426310749119a015e25/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/FileIO/TextFieldParser.vb) was 3 years ago. Its also one of the [slowest .NET parsers](https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers),  7 times slower than CsvHelper, the de-facto standard

Comment: @dbc I found out about Sep from the [CSV parsers benchmarl](https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers). It's the fastest parser, 40-50 times faster than TextFieldParser with an API that's still easier to use than TextFieldParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `x.Replace("", "0")` throws is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace):

> **Definition**
>
> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.
>
> **Exceptions**
> `ArgumentNullException` - oldValue is null.
> `ArgumentException` - **`oldValue` is the empty string ("").**

Keeping in mind that strings in C# are immutable, if you want to replace empty or whitespace strings with `"0"`, you can do:

```
x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) ? "0" : x
```